# issue in increasing disk size in ubuntu guest vmware

Tags: lvm, partition, ubuntu-14.04, diskpart, pv

Have followed [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/420070/increasing-disk-size-of-linux-guest-in-vmware)

I was trying to increase the size of my disk allocated to ubuntu guest in vmware below are the things i have already done

```
Increased max setting in vmware settings - Done

Partition the new disk space - Done
    fdisk /dev/sda
    created primary partion
    changed system type of partition 4 to 8e (Linux LVM)
    scaning

root@ubuntu:~# partprobe -s

/dev/sda: msdos partitions 1 3 2 <5> 4
```

3.Increasing the logical volume

root@ubuntu:~# pvcreate /dev/sda4

Physical volume "/dev/sda4" successfully created

4.here is the main issue

```
root@ubuntu:~# vgdisplay
No volume groups found

expected :-
root@ubuntu:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu
  xxxxx                 xxxxxx
```

Also tried pvdisplay it gives no vg-name but why ?????

```
root@ubuntu:~# pvdisplay
  "/dev/sda4" is a new physical volume of "14.00 GiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda4
  VG Name               
  PV Size               14.00 GiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0   
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               syysU7-5XI0-swB9-aOPJ-ur2c-R0Ys-OnPWYf


root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 36.5 GB, 36507222016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4438 cylinders, total 71303168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d1d96

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    35127295    17562624   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        35129342    41940991     3405825    5  Extended
/dev/sda3        35127296    35129341        1023   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4        41940992    71303167    14681088   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda5        35129344    41940991     3405824   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Any idea why it shows "No volume groups found"

Comment: Do you already use LVM for the rest of the system? There will not be a volume group if you (or the OS installer) never created it with `vgcreate`.

Comment: @Sven  i am extending disk first time and was using default setup of ubuntu os till now .....any suggestion

Comment: Read up on how LVM works. Just don't blindly follow tutorials or answers on SF without understanding what you are doing and why. For now, please add the output of  `fdisk -l` to your question to show us all partitions on the system.

Comment: @Sven have added fdisk -l and shows my new /dev/sda4

Comment: Please provide the output of pvs; vgs; lvs    - This will provide a summary of your Logical Volume Setup.   It seems to me that you have not set up volume group or logical volume - indeed it looks to me like your VM is not using logical volumes which means your approach can not work.